# Similarity measure between graphs using NetworkX

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have **two graphs A** and **B**. They may be isomorphic, completely different, or have some similarities(few nodes are the same, or few of the nodes share the same edges).

I want to see/check **how different/similar these graphs are**. 
networkx.is_isomorphic() is a way. However, this does not say more than just true or false.

For example, the difference(A,B) function returns a new graph that contains the edges that exist in A but not in B; but it needs to have the same number of nodes.

My graphs, A and B, **do not have the same number of nodes.** And may have a **few hundred nodes.** So the algrithms will be best if not NP-Hard (Like the graph_edit_distance() function that is NP Hard).

Comment: What does "similar" mean in your context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure it's quite what you're looking for, but hopefully you might find some of this useful. Let's take the following graphs `G` and `H` for instance:

```
l1 = [['A','C'], ['A', 'D'], ['I','F'], ['K', 'E'], ['D', 'A'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
l2 = [['A','B'], ['Q', 'D'], ['J','F'], ['A', 'E'], ['D', 'F'], ['X','A']]

G = nx.from_edgelist(l1)
H = nx.from_edgelist(l2)

G.nodes()
# NodeView(('A', 'C', 'D', 'I', 'F', 'K', 'E', 'B'))
H.nodes()
# NodeView(('A', 'B', 'Q', 'D', 'J', 'F', 'E', 'X'))
```

In order to get a similarity *measure*, you could probably come up with some custom definition of similarity or difference, considering the intersection of union of edges. Perhaps the [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) could be a good candidate:

```
def jaccard_similarity(g, h):
    i = set(g).intersection(h)
    return round(len(i) / (len(g) + len(h) - len(i)),3)

jaccard_similarity(G.edges(), H.edges())
# 0.091
```

---

What probably is also useful here is to come up with a visualisation that gives an idea of how similar *and* different both graphs are. We could start by using [`compose`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.compose.html), which will give us the simple union of the node sets and edge sets:

```
GH = nx.compose(G,H)
GH.nodes()
# NodeView(('A', 'C', 'D', 'I', 'F', 'K', 'E', 'B', 'Q', 'J', 'X'))
```

And iterate over the composed graph's edges and nodes, and assign to these a *color* depending on which graph they belong to (including both at the same time too). This could also be extended to adding some *attribute* indicating to which graph it belongs too:

```
# set edge colors
edge_colors = dict()
for edge in GH.edges():
    if G.has_edge(*edge):
        if H.has_edge(*edge):
            edge_colors[edge] = 'magenta'
            continue
        edge_colors[edge] = 'lightgreen'
    elif H.has_edge(*edge):
        edge_colors[edge] = 'lightblue'

# set node colors
G_nodes = set(G.nodes())
H_nodes = set(H.nodes())
node_colors = []
for node in GH.nodes():
    if node in G_nodes:
        if node in H_nodes:
            node_colors.append('magenta')
            continue
        node_colors.append('lightgreen')
    if node in H_nodes:
        node_colors.append('lightblue')
```

So here the intersecting nodes and edges will have a *magenta* color. Otherwise they'll be *green* or *blue* if they belong to the *G* or *H* `Graph` respectively.

We can now plot the graph using the above dictionary/list of edge and node colors respectively. This should give quite a good way to see of both the *intersecting* and *disjoint* nodes/edges on both graphs:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(GH, scale=20)
nx.draw(GH, pos, 
        nodelist=GH.nodes(),
        node_color=node_colors,
        edgelist=edge_colors.keys(), 
        edge_color=edge_colors.values(),
        node_size=800,
        width=8,alpha=0.5,
        with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for some form of Jaccard re edges, or edges and nodes.  I use Jaccard a lot, it’s simple conceptually once you get it and really quite good for all sorts of set/membership problems.  First thing I thought of reading the question.  Most impressed with the intersection viz too!

Comment: Do you think [graph_edit_distance](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.similarity.graph_edit_distance.html#networkx.algorithms.similarity.graph_edit_distance) would be good enough, especially for simple graphs, like trees?