# Weighted Jaccard Similarity for Two Networks with Networkx

Tags: python, networkx, similarity

I am using Python networkx to compute the Jaccard similarity of the following 2 networks:

```
G.edges(data=True)
OutEdgeDataView([('v1', 'a', {'weight': 1}), ('v1', 'b', {'weight': 1}), ('a', 'd', {'weight': 1}), ('a', '11', {'weight': 7}), ('b', 'v4', {'weight': 1}), ('b', 'v9', {'weight': 1}), ('v9', 'b', {'weight': 1})])

K.edges(data=True)
OutEdgeDataView([('v1', 'asssssss', {'weight': 1}), ('v1', 'b', {'weight': 1}), ('asssssss', 'd', {'weight': 1}), ('asssssss', '11', {'weight': 7}), ('b', 'asssssss', {'weight': 10}), ('b', 'd', {'weight': 10}), ('v9', 'b', {'weight': 1})])
```

I am using the following solution kindly provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421491/similarity-measure-between-graphs-using-networkx):

```
def jaccard_similarity(g, h):
    i = set(g).intersection(h)
    return round(len(i) / (len(g) + len(h) - len(i)),6)

jaccard_similarity(G.edges(), K.edges())
0.166667
```

However, I need to extend this calculation to a [weighted jaccard measure (distance or similarity)](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/it//pubs/archive/36928.pdf) that **takes into account arc weights** and works both for directed and undirected networks, which could have different edges and nodes.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the weighted Jaccard, we need to define a vector. If we treat union of all edges as our vector dimensions, then our weights for each graph form a coordinate in that space.

```
def weighted_jaccard(g1, g2):
    edges = set(g1.edges()).union(g2.edges())
    mins, maxs = 0, 0
    for edge in edges:
        weight1 = g1.get_edge_data(*edge, {}).get('weight', 0)
        weight2 = g2.get_edge_data(*edge, {}).get('weight', 0)
        mins += min(weight1, weight2)
        maxs += max(weight1, weight2)
    return mins / maxs
```

This definition is consistent with the non-weighted Jaccard when all of the weights are 1.

It's worth pointing out that once you've defined your vectors in this way, you could apply pretty much any R<sup>n</sup> distance metric.