# Finding index for similarities between two graphs

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, similarity

I have two networkx DiGraph, both have the same nodes that are of two different type:

One is saved as a positive integer and is called **address** (for example in a graph i have address 1,2,3,4)

The other one is a negative one, called **transaction** ( for example -1,-2)

Now I have a real graph made like **address**->**transaction**->**address**  (like 1,2->(-1)->3 than 3->(-2)->1,4) and the other one with simulated edges (while preserving some "rules" that are true in the first graph, like that an address can't be both a *sender* and a *receiver* in the same transaction)

Both graphs have three attributes for the **address** nodes: balance, in-degree, out-degree

I need to create an (or more) index of similarity between the two graphs  [similar to the Jaccard index in the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421491/similarity-measure-between-graphs-using-networkx) but also in different ways, even by using the attributes (I was thinking about comparing their distributions)

Do someone know a good algorithm to do that?

Comment: Since you say both graph have the same nodes, but different edges, how about simply taking the number of edges in the symmetric difference of the two sets of edges? Perhaps weighted by the value of the transaction.

Comment: You can get the symmetric difference of the two sets of edges using either of the two notations `^` or `.set_difference()`: `frozenset(tuple(sorted(e)) for e in G.edges) ^ frozenset(tuple(sorted(e)) for e in H.edges)` or `frozenset(tuple(sorted(e)) for e in G.edges).symmetric_difference(tuple(sorted(e)) for e in H.edges)`

Comment: @Stef with symmetric difference you mean the union of the two sets without the intersection? And the transaction does not have a unique value, one could have more than one sender and more than one receiver (as written in the example)

Comment: Ok thanks, that could be a solution. Obviously I leave the question open in case of some other good answer!